# Is there a way to filter pattern with double wildcard (percentage)?

Tags: filter, makefile

I'd like to filter theses lines:

```
VAR_LIST += TEST_ORANGE_1_A
VAR_LIST += TEST_BLUE_1_A
VAR_LIST += TEST_BLUE_1_B
VAR_LIST += TEST_BLUE_2_A
VAR_LIST += TEST_BLUE_2_B
VAR_LIST += TEST_RED_1_A
VAR_LIST += TEST_RED_4_C
```

using the following-like filter patterns:

```
TEST_X_X_X = $(filter TEST_%,$(VAR_LIST))                  #works
TEST_ORANGE_X_X = $(filter TEST_ORANGE_%,$(VAR_LIST))      #works
TEST_X_1_X = $(filter TEST_%_1_%,$(VAR_LIST))              #does not work
TEST_X_X_A = $(filter TEST_%_A,$(VAR_LIST))                #works
TEST_X_X_A = $(filter TEST_%_2_B,$(VAR_LIST))              #works
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Note: I am adding the following constraint, i get my VAR_LIST from the `.VARIABLES` makefile env.

Comment: Why do you say the last two "do not work"?  It would help a lot if you showed what results you got and explained why they were wrong or explained what you wanted to get.  They seem like they would work to me.

Comment: It is not possible to have a filter on two different patterns.  The second `%` is treated as a literal.  If you need to do this you either have to (a) use `$(shell ...)` to drop into a more powerful interpreter, or (b) use some tricky stuff which will rely on knowing _exactly_ what kind of thing you need to do and the restrictions you are able to put in place.  For example, if you know that the names are always separated by "_" and there are exactly 4 elements, you can write a make function that will split the name into words then you can check individual words.

Comment: sorry, i had wrong "does not work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found:

```
regex_filter=$(shell echo '$(2)' | tr ' ' '\n' | grep '$(1)' | tr '\n' ' ')
```

now:

```
TEST_X_X_X = $(call regex_filter, TEST_.*,$(VAR_LIST))                  #works
TEST_ORANGE_X_X = $(call regex_filter, TEST_ORANGE_.*,$(VAR_LIST))      #works
TEST_X_1_X = $(call regex_filter, TEST_.*_1_.*,$(VAR_LIST))              #works
TEST_X_X_A = $(call regex_filter, TEST_.*_A,$(VAR_LIST))                #works
TEST_X_X_A = $(call regex_filter, TEST_.*_2_B,$(VAR_LIST))              #works
```

Comment: What made you disregard the gmtt solution?

Comment: In both cases I have to define a function (regex_filter or filter-glob). gmtt solution even adds an include. So I'd rather use a very flexible and standard regex than gmtt, even if your solution does work. Anyway, your solution might deserve a +1 after all :)

Comment: "it even adds an include" ... this is a weak argument. If you want extended functionality in programming you either program it yourself on the spot or you access a library. We both do that with the difference that gmtt is platform neutral while you bind your solution to a Unix system and the knowledge of not only regex but also shell programming - no offense meant.

Answer (score 1):

The [GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) has a function `glob-match` which does what you want. It matches against the simple version of [globs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), that is `*`,`?` and `[...]` denoted character classes.
It does not verbatim replace `filter` because `glob-match` is able to match   (space  characters) also, so it is not able to process its input as a `make` list. Thats not much of problem tho, just define a helper function `filter-glob`:

```
include gmtt.mk

VAR_LIST += TEST_ORANGE_1_A
VAR_LIST += TEST_BLUE_1_A
VAR_LIST += TEST_BLUE_1_B
VAR_LIST += TEST_BLUE_2_A
VAR_LIST += TEST_BLUE_2_B
VAR_LIST += TEST_RED_1_A
VAR_LIST += TEST_RED_4_C


filter-glob = $(foreach str,$2,$(if $(call glob-match,$(str),$1),$(str)))

$(info $(call filter-glob,TEST_*,$(VAR_LIST)))    
$(info $(call filter-glob,TEST_ORANGE_*,$(VAR_LIST))) 
$(info $(call filter-glob,TEST_*_1_*,$(VAR_LIST)))
$(info $(call filter-glob,TEST_*_A,$(VAR_LIST)))   
$(info $(call filter-glob,TEST_*_2_B,$(VAR_LIST)))
```

Output:

```
$ make
TEST_ORANGE_1_A TEST_BLUE_1_A TEST_BLUE_1_B TEST_BLUE_2_A TEST_BLUE_2_B TEST_RED_1_A TEST_RED_4_C
TEST_ORANGE_1_A
TEST_ORANGE_1_A TEST_BLUE_1_A TEST_BLUE_1_B   TEST_RED_1_A
TEST_ORANGE_1_A TEST_BLUE_1_A  TEST_BLUE_2_A  TEST_RED_1_A
    TEST_BLUE_2_B
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Take care however, that globs aren't regular expressions. A pattern like `*_1_*` will match `V_1_0_` as well as `V_2_1_` because it just eats away indifferently on the input stream with `*`. As long as your pattern don't become too involved, globs are a quite usable substitute for re's tho.